# Error when using Vgg16 output and adding extra custom layers. ValueError: Error when checking input

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, vgg-net

I am trying to take the outputs of images (train and validation) passed through a Vgg16 network with `include_top = false` , and then adding the final few layers as can be seen in the code below.

I want `x` to store the complete model so that I can create a tflite file out of it(including vgg and the layers being added by me)

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
import os

x= vgg16.output
print(x.shape)
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)

x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(100)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(x)
x = (Dropout(0.5)) (x)
x = (Dense(50)) (x) 
x = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3)(x)
x = Dropout(0.3)(x)
x = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(x)


# this is the model we will train
model = Model(inputs=vgg16.input, outputs=x)

# first: train only the top layers (which were randomly initialized)
# i.e. freeze all convolutional InceptionV3 layers
for layer in vgg16.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
   optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=1e-4),
   metrics=['acc'])

# train the model on the new data for a few epochs
history = model.fit(train_data, train_labels, 
   epochs=15,
   batch_size=batch_size,
   validation_data=(validation_data, validation_labels))

model.save(top_model_weights_path)
(eval_loss, eval_accuracy) = model.evaluate( 
    validation_data, validation_labels, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1)
```

The output of `x.shape` is (?, ?, ?, 512)

`train_data.shape` (1660, 2, 2, 512)

`train_labels.shape` (1660, 4)

`validation_data.shape` (137, 4)

`validation_labels.shape` (137, 2, 2, 512)

Error:

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_3 to have shape (None, None, 3) but got array with shape (2, 2, 512)

This error occurs on the line:

> 52    validation_data=(validation_data, validation_labels))

---

A previous code snippet as seen below works perfectly fine and gives accurate outputs. `train_data` stores a numpy array of `vgg16.predict_generator()`

```
model = Sequential() 
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=train_data.shape[1:])) 
model.add(Dense(100)) 
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
model.add(Dropout(0.5)) 
model.add(Dense(50)) 
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3))
model.add(Dropout(0.3)) 
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
   optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=1e-4),
   metrics=['acc'])
history = model.fit(train_data, train_labels, 
   epochs=15,
   batch_size=batch_size,
   validation_data=(validation_data, validation_labels),
   callbacks =[tensorboard])
model.save(top_model_weights_path)
(eval_loss, eval_accuracy) = model.evaluate( 
    validation_data, validation_labels, batch_size=batch_size,     verbose=1)
print("[INFO] accuracy: {:.2f}%".format(eval_accuracy * 100)) 
print("[INFO] Loss: {}".format(eval_loss))
```

This step for passing all the images (train, validation, test; here only train is shown) through vgg16 is done for both the above snippets of code

```
train_data_dir = 'data/train'
validation_data_dir = 'data/validation'
test_data_dir = 'data/test'

# number of epochs to train top model 
epochs = 7 #this has been changed after multiple model run 
# batch size used by flow_from_directory and predict_generator 
batch_size = 32

#Loading vgc16 model
vgg16 = applications.VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255) 
generator = datagen.flow_from_directory( 
    validation_data_dir, 
    target_size=(img_width, img_height), 
    batch_size=batch_size, 
    class_mode=None, 
    shuffle=False) 

nb_train_samples = len(generator.filenames) 
num_classes = len(generator.class_indices) 

predict_size_train = int(math.ceil(nb_train_samples / batch_size)) 

train_data = vgg16.predict_generator(generator, predict_size_train)
```

Comment: Can you show, how do you define the VGG model?

Comment: @Yoskutik at the end I have added the image processing part which shows the vgg definition. train_data stores the output of the images after they have been passed through vgg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well...

1. You defined the `target_size=(img_width, img_height)` and if `(img_width, img_height)` is not `(224, 224)` then you need also do define `target_size` in the VGG model:

```py
vgg16 = applications.VGG16(
  include_top=False, 
  weights='imagenet',
  target_size=(img_width, img_height, 3))
```

2. Why do you use `class_mode=None` in the `datagen.flow_from_directory`? `None` is a default value. If you want to make it *categorical* write `class_mode='categorical'`, but using `class_mode=None` doesn't make sense at all.
3. `predict_generator` returns predictions. Right now `predict_generator` is deprecated, but you can use `predict` which works OK with generators. But `predict` should be used after training. The right way of using generators is:

```py
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255) 
generator = datagen.flow_from_directory( 
  train_data_dir, 
  target_size=(img_width, img_height), 
  batch_size=batch_size, 
  shuffle=False)
// ...
history = model.fit(
  generator,
  epochs=15,
  steps_per_epoch=len(generator), 
  batch_size=batch_size,
  validation_data=validation_generator,
  validation_steps=len(validation_generator))
```

and later, if you want to make a prediction use: `model.predict(test_generator)`

4. You don't need to use `Flatten` after `GlobalAveragePooling2D` in this case. `GlobalAveragePooling2D` will reduce output to a 1D array.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. 
Just one small change, instead of target_size in application.VGG16 as it is a model, input_tensor=Input(shape=(img_height, img_width, 3))) should be used.